# Problem with Prefix in Discord.js (including .toUpperCase())

Tags: api, bots, discord, discord.js

Basically, I've been developing a bot for several weeks now using the discord.js library and recently encountered a small but crucial issue. Essentially when I declare my argument, I also made it so that the message content (message.content) would be capitalized using .toUpperCase(). Essentially in doing so regardless of the type of prefix you would enter (symbol wise) it would all be read by the program as valid.

For example only: !help - should work, however if I would enter .help, it would also be read as valid.

In any case, here's the code. I appreciate all the help!

```
bot.on('message', message =>{
    let args = message.content.toUpperCase().substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    const sender = message.member;

    switch(args[0])
    {
    case 'HELP':
            message.reply("I've sent you some documentation on all the commands that you can use...").then(d_msg => {d_msg.delete(3000); });
            message.delete(3000);
            const attachment = new Attachment('./UtilityBot_Documentation.txt') 
            message.author.send('[Education] Bot - Documentation');
            message.author.send(attachment);
            break;
    }
})
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The discord.js tutorial covers an extremely similar problem to what you're trying to do. I recommend you check it out. The page I linked in specific is doing a very similar thing to you, but it's worth giving the whole thing a read through if you haven't done so already. In general, I would include the following line just above where you established args.

> if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

What I'm doing here is saying if the message does not start with the prefix, stop running until a new message is sent. I might be missing something, but certainly check out the tutorial. It's really well written.

https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#basic-arguments